# Aggregate training results to predits

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When training the model the results depend on the sampling. In order to obtain something better you could repeat the training (in another randomly create training sample, using [Ffolds](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold), [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) ... ), somehow aggregate the results and have this way a result that will be more robust that one create in a particular case alone. **Question: is it already implemented in sklearn or similar?**. Apologies is this is a straighforward question, I haven't see a simple solution.

I see that there is a function called [cross_val_predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) however my first impresion having a quick look to the source code is that it predecits as many times as trains and I would like to predicts only ones, so I can piclke the, somehow aggregate results, and predict later, instead of repeat the whole training thing again.

Comment: I think you are confusing some concepts and may need to do a bit of reading. What model are you using? If your trained model is dependent on the train/test split (which you can identify using cross-validation) then you are overfitting and need to tune your hyperparameters to avoid this. As an alternative strategy: is there something in sklearn that aggregates overfitted classifiers to produce a more robust classifier? Yes, it is called a random forest!

Comment: Your are right ensembling methods are doing the job very well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. You could perhaps use the knowledge you have learned in your notebook to create your own ensemble classifier once you have pushed Random Forest as far as you can. Train, say, RF, Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression models and then design a way of ensembling the results. For example, you could fit a 2nd level classifier (log. reg.) to your features and the 3 predict.proba() results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I think the best option are the [ensemblers in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html).

I left here the solution I was using before. I am pretty sure could be improved (as mentioned before the [Ensemblers in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)) are better. I have placed here https://github.com/rafaelvalero/aggreating_predictions_sklearn, where I have left a notebook with and example (using iris database), in case anyone can play around and see in details how could be done.

That solution will train models (in parallel, using joblib), pickle the trained model (a model from SKlearn), store the results (using joblib dump)  and later would recover them to create predictions (in parallel, using joblib) that later are aggregated.